# Customize Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a script that I want to execute using Task Scheduler at certain intervals that are different:

1. I want it to run every hour in the day time (between 8 AM and 11 PM)
2. I want it to run every 10 minutes late night and early morning (between 12 AM and 7 AM).

Could someone advise me if Windows Server 2008 R2 Task Scheduler is customizable for that?

I could just have two Scheduled Tasks that use the same script, with each on a different schedule (on for the hourly and another for the every 10 minute schedule)... But I'd prefer to have one Scheduled Task if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want the same one task scheduled with Windows Task Scheduler to run:

1. Every 10 minutes between 12 AM and 7 AM every day—starting at 12 AM first run and ending at 7 AM last run
2. You need this to also run between 8 AM and 11 PM  every hour every day—starting at 8 AM for the first run and ending at 11 PM for the last run

This is possible by scheduling it with multiple triggers as shown in the below screen shots and the **Important Options to Pick** section.

When you create the task with Task Scheduler, go to the `Triggers` tab, select <kbd>New</kbd>, and you'll get the options to specify as in the below screen shots.

You may have to pick the 12 hours option from the `for duration of` drop down and then *replace* the **"12"** with **"7"** or **"15"** where applicable manually with the keyboard.

> **Essentially you are creating two schedules\triggers...**
>
> - One starting at 12 AM and running for a duration of 7 hours (until 7 AM) every 10 minutes.
> - The other starting at 8 AM and running for a duration of 15 hours (until 11 PM) every 1 hour.

**Important Options to Pick (per below screen shots)**

- The `Settings` area options needs to be set to `Daily`
- The `Start:` time needs to be specified correctly
- The `Recur every:` option needs to be **1** `days`
- The `Repeat task every` option needs checked, and specified correctly
- The `For duration of:` needs to be specified correctly
- The `Enabled` option needs to be checked

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It worked like a charm :)